# Where to place content area in HTML5

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple page in html5. I saw many tutorials but didn't find the content area of per page, for example i have seen the following code in html5 below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML5 Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<hgroup>
<h1>HTML5 Template</h1>
<h3>Pretty standard template</h3>
</hgroup>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About HTML5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
<hgroup></hgroup>
<address></address>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code you can see there is no content area defined which will display in my main page content. I actually  need to create the following layout in html as per shown in the following image.

[image: Layout image]

So i need to create html5 page just like in the image above. What iam missing in my html code to achive the same thing like in the image. Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:
[image: I Need to make this layout aligned centralized]

Comment: What do you mean by "no content area" ? Please be more explicit.

Comment: 1) The "content areas" *CAN BE ANYTHING IN YOUR HTML BODY*!!!!  2) How and where you lay things out are completely up to you.  There are infinite choices, and many ways to accomplish each choice!  3) In general, however, your *BEST BET* is to define "areas" with HTML "div" tags, then associate CSS with your tags.  Jyothi Babu Araja gives a good example below.  *YOU REALLY NEED TO STUDY A BIT MORE* on basic HTML, CSS (and, yes, Javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you required template
Use this in you `style.css`

```css
.page{
width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.header{
height:60px;
  width:100%;
  background:#E1E1E1;
  font-size:20px;
}
.navigation{
background:#F0F0F0;
}
.left{
width:20%;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  background:#F6F6F6;
  height:800px;
  text-align:center;
}

.main-content{
width:80%;
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  background:#FFF;
  height:800px;
}
.footer{
width:100%;
  background:#E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <linl rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="page">
      <div class="header">
      Header
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
      Navigation (this can be used as nav tag)
      </div>
       <div class="page-wrapper">
       <div class="left">
           
             <li>menu1</li>
             <li>menu1</li>
             <li>menu1</li>
             <li>menu1</li>
             <li>menu1</li>
            
       </div>
       <div class="main-content">
          Right column (Your Content Area)   
       </div>
       </div>
        <div class="footer">
        Footer content  
        </div>
       
      </div>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Above Jyothi example is very nice and iam close to getting my answer, actually html5 tags like <header> <nav> <footer> confused me. As you use <header> tag, likewise i iam trying to place <nav> and <footer> tag in your example, Can you please edit your code to place these tags at the right place, secondly is there any specifc <content> tag introducd in html5? like <header><nav><footer> tags. Thanks and sorry for my silly questions...

Comment: Check the updated one. Not necessary to use `<header>` and `<nav>` tags. we can achieve them like this

Comment: Thanks Jyothi, My confusion is no more now :). I need to ask one last thing that iam trying to remove the top margin but did'nt succeded. If you run an example then see at above of the header there is an empty space. How to remove it? thanks.

Comment: Keep this latest code into `html` and `style.css` files

Comment: Thanks, please allow me to ask one more question, i have made the page width 980px and when i do this my all layout aligned left. how to make it centralized, please view image in my orignal question as Edit, i just need to make it centralized, really happy and appreciate your help :).

Comment: just add `text-align:center` to `div` where you want your text to be centered. See the update

Comment: I did'nt mean like this, please see screenshot in my EDIT. When i make .page class from 100% to 980px, i got empty space at the right side of the layout, so i need to centralized the whole layout. for example when i write <div align="Center">  other sub divs </div> it resolved but there must be a decent way to do this, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102075/discussion-between-rauf-abid-and-jyothi-babu-araja).